# how to get some value from url using jstl

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect

I have two forms those have `same-url` for `action`, the following form is on page `http://www.domain.com/pre-foo-url`, which is

```
<form:form commandName="some" class="form" action="/app/same-url">
    <form:input path="title"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="foo"/>
    <button>OK</button>
</form:form>
```

and the other form is on `http://www.domain.com/bar/{id}`

```
 <form:form commandName="some" class="form" action="/app/same-url">
    <form:input path="tile"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="bar"/>
    <button>OK</button>
 </form:form>
```

two methods in my controller, one for deciding to redirect to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/same-url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleRedirect(@RequestParam("redirect") String redirect) {
    if (redirect.equals("foo")) {               
        return "redirect:/foo";         
    } else {
        return "redirect:/bar/{id}"; // this {id} must get the value from http://www.domain.com/bar/{id}<-- Here
    }
}
```

other method for getting the value of id from `return "redirect:/bar/{id}";` and goto `/bar/{id}` request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleBar(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    // some logic here 
    return "go-any-where";
}
```

Now how can I get value from `http://www.domain.com/bar/{id}` and set that when I redirect it to `redirect:/bar/{id}`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution for your need, first I must point out your need then I will write my answer.

> **First:**
>
> -You need to get the `/{id}` from `http://www.domain.com/bar/{id}`, it means you want to get the value of **last part** of url.

you can get that value adding following code on page `http://www.domain.com/bar/{id}`

```
<c:set var="currentPage" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}"/> <!--This will give you the path to current page eg- http://www.domain.com/bar/360 -->
<c:set var="splitURI" value="${fn:split(currentPage, '/')}"/> <!--This will split the path of current page -->
<c:set var="lastValue" value="${splitURI[fn:length(splitURI)-1]}"/><!--This will give you the last value of url "360" in this case -->
<c:out value="${lastValue}"></c:out> <!--use this to make sure you are getting correct value(for testing only) -->
```

> **Scond:**
>
> -You have to pass value of `/{id}` which is got from `http://www.domain.com/bar/{id}`.

pass this using the form as.

```
<form:form commandName="some" class="form" action="/app/same-url">
   <form:input path="title"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="bar"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="path-var" value="${lastValue}"/>
   <button>OK</button>
<form:form>
```

> **At Last:**
>
> -You want to be redirected to `redirect:/bar/{id}"`.

this could be done using the method below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-category", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleRedirect(@RequestParam("redirect") String redirect, @RequestParam("path-var") String pathVar) {
        if (redirect.equals("foo")) {               
            return "redirect:/foo";         
        } else {
            return "redirect:/bar/" + pathVar;  
        }
    }
```

### Important

> This is not the Last/Best solution for the problem above.

there may be other/better solutions to this one.

> Add this tag lib `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>`, when using any jstl function just as `fn:length()`.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Great that was the original need and this answer fulfills that, I guess the title is not appropriate for the context of the issue mentioned, any suggestions?